# MD5 not matching openssl md5

Tags: openssl, md5

Hi i need to rewrite hash algorithm of md5 for school and meanwhile i was looking through interne i found this [site](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1321):

At the end is written:

```
MD5 test suite:
MD5 ("") = d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
MD5 ("a") = 0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661
MD5 ("abc") = 900150983cd24fb0d6963f7d28e17f72
MD5 ("message digest") = f96b697d7cb7938d525a2f31aaf161d0
MD5 ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz") = c3fcd3d76192e4007dfb496cca67e13b
MD5 ("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789") =
d174ab98d277d9f5a5611c2c9f419d9f
MD5 ("123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456
78901234567890") = 57edf4a22be3c955ac49da2e2107b67a
```

But when i try the same samples in openssl md5:

```
~ >>> echo "a" | openssl dgst -md5                                        
(stdin)= 60b725f10c9c85c70d97880dfe8191b3
```

Is not matching, why is this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that echo was printing a newline i only used printf instead echo and now is matching